# On click of button, I want to validate the data and if true i want the delete-confirmation dialog.. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two date pickers, from date and to date, and a delete button.
On click of delete, validation should be done if from date is greater than to date and etc then the delete-confirmation popover should come displaying yes or no.
If clicked on yes, the delete callback should be called else it will return false!

How to do so??
Any help would be appreciated

**This is my code**

```
"#Delete click": function(el, ev) {
  this.validate();
  this.confirmation("#Delete", "Are you sure?", "Yes", "No", this.deleteConfirmCallback, this);
},

confirmation: function(element, text, yesText, noText, yesCallback, context) {
  $(element).confirmation({
    title: text,
    singleton: true,
    popout: true,
    btnOkClass: "btn btn-sm default-color",
    btnCancelClass: "btn btn-sm primary-color text-case ",
    btnOkLabel: yesText,
    btnCancelLabel: noText,
    btnOkIcon: "glyphicon-tiny glyphicon-ok",
    btnCancelIcon: "glyphicon-tiny glyphicon-remove",
    onConfirm: function() {
      yesCallback(context, this);
    }
  });    
},
```

> Blockquote

For the first time click I'm not able to get that delete-confirmation popup

> Blockquote

Comment: what is  "#Delete click", it could be due to 'this' keyword your code not work, please share more on this

Comment: return true in method of this.validate(); if data is valid else return false.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
if('#btn').click(function(){
    if($('#fromDate').val() > $('#toDate').val())  
    // You can also make a function to check this and call it here
    {
        // Open delete confirm
        // Check if user select OK or cancel and make an ajax call to delete if use select delete option
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap popup?

Comment: bootstrap-confirmation plugin

Comment: Anu you have to explicitly show the modal if condition succeed. Try some thing like this: $('#modal_id').modal('show');

Comment: "#Delete click": function (el, ev) {
                try {                   
                    if (this.validate()) {
                       this.confirmation("#Delete", "Are you sure?", "Yes", "No", this.deleteConfirmCallback, this);
                    }
                } catch (ex) {
                    this.showMessage("Error");
                }
            },

Comment: No.. But i found an alternative

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this:

```
var from_date = $("#from_date").val();
var to_date = $("#to_date").val();
if(from_date > to_date) {
   //true condition statement
   // should be alert or confirmation
} else {
   //false condition statement
   // should be alert or confirmation
}
```

Comment: validation part is fine but not able to fire the bootstrap-confirmation